# Reverse search not working in Linux

Tags: linux

I am doing ctrl + r to find an old command which I used earlier. But it seems the shell does not understand this. If it is disabled, how do I enable it?

Comment: what distribution and console do you use?

Comment: SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 11 (x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

what if you try to bind the command again

bind '"\C-r": reverse-search-history'

I hope this helps somehow